# Linked list node link issue

Tags: c

I'm trying to create linked list, but the nodes are not linked properly. I'm missing something in my code & i don't know what it is.

```
typedef struct sllist{
    int x;
    struct sllist *next;
} slilist;

slilist *head=NULL, *tail=NULL;

void add_to_List(int val){
    slilist *temp = malloc(sizeof(slilist));
    temp->x = val;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(!head){
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }else{
        tail->next = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int y;
    for(y = 0; y<10; y++)
        add_to_List(y);

    while(head){
        printf("%d\n",head->x);
        head=head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my output is :

```
0
9
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
if(!head) {
    head=temp;
    tail=temp;
} else {
    tail->next=temp;
    tail = temp;
}
```

In fact, you forget to change `tail` in `else` statement:

```
tail = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

You failed to update `tail`, so the new elements are all linked after the head.

```
void add_to_List(int val){
    slilist *temp = malloc(sizeof(slilist));
    temp->x=val;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(!head){
        head=temp;
        tail=temp;
    }else{
        tail->next=temp;
        tail=tail->next; /* add this line */
    }
}
```

Also you should `free()` everything you allocated via `malloc()`.

```
int main()
{
    int y;
    for(y=0; y<10; y++)
        add_to_List(y);

    while(head){
        slilist *head_bak = head; /* add this line */
        printf("%d\n",head->x);
        head=head->next;
        free(head_bak); /* add this line */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add below code :

```
typedef struct sllist{
    int x;
    struct sllist *next;
} slilist;

slilist *head=NULL, *tail=NULL;

void add_to_List(int val){
    slilist *temp = malloc(sizeof(slilist));
    temp->x = val;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(!head){
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }else{
        while (tail->next !=NULL)
    {
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    tail->next = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int y;
    for(y = 0; y<10; y++)
        add_to_List(y);

    while(head){
        printf("%d\n",head->x);
        head=head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```